# SQL Server, the best way import 1M records every second?

Tags: sql-server

What is the best way to import 1M records into SQL Server every second?

Namely, I have a large data feed which need to be saved into database. One row has about 75 columns, so it's a really large amount of data.

Comment: How much money do you have to throw at hardware?

Comment: In what way is the data received? Files? Web Service? Some custom protocol? Your source will make a difference in how this can be handled. Also, is this continuous or is there a burst of this activity followed by slower or no activity?

Comment: It's MS SQL Server 2008R2. We are getting data via web service and data is coming almost entire day. Over night, amount of data is much less.

Answer (score 6):

See Henk's article [SQL2008 R2 DCE on a 96 core Unisys ES7000 server with DSI Solid State storage: Bulk Inserting 1 Terabyte within 10 minutes](http://henkvandervalk.com/sql2008-r2-dce-on-a-96-core-unisys-es7000-server-with-dsi-solid-state-storage-bulk-inserting-1-terabyte-within-10-minutes). He gives a really good explanation of how they achieved this.

Comment: 96 cores. Now that's a top machine for gaming! You could gang up on people all by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

If you will be able to achieve will depend on several factors, but the fastest ways to import data into sql server are Bulk Inserts (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) and SSIS packages

Comment: I'm using bulk insert right now but sometimes I'm getting 'Timeout expired' error.

Comment: humm..can you be more specific?

Answer (score 3):

Throw the feeds into files, then let SQL import them at its leisure.

Unless SQL needs them in real time?  In that case you are probably looking at a database residing in some kind of ram disc.